# Filenames missing from ListDirectoryDetails

Tags: c#

I am trying to get all files in a ftp directory however I am having issues its not bringing back all files. But the first to files its not getting the file name for some weird reason so then my program skips it.

```
public static string[] GetFilesInDirectory(string requestUriString, string username, string password)
    {
        var lines = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            var request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(requestUriString);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);                
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
            request.UsePassive = true;

            using (WebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            string line;

                            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    lines.Add(line);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("An error occured connecting to the website.", ex);
        }

        return lines.ToArray();
 }
```

When I look at the files you wil  see here that the first two are missing there names.

You will see that the file names are missing the count is correct but no idea why the file names are blank.

Sorry there are thirteen files so where is it even getting the extra two array entries.
  [image]

Here is the files as well on the server as u see there is 13 files.

And here is my array of files.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

They're not missing, you just didn't look closely enough.  Single dot `.` represents the current directory and double dot `..` represents the parent directory.

https://superuser.com/a/37451/255404

Comment: but I cant for the life of me see the orders300418.csv

Comment: @DavidB All of them are returned, look at index [5] :)

Comment: yeah sorry I see that how would one get the lattest file